# Attribute Error of different gdal version in python - gdal.RegisterAll

Tags: python, gdal, python-import

i've coded a small python program, which is used on varying Operating systems and with different **gdal** versions.

I'm using Debian Linux (Python 2.7.3 and Gdal 1.9.0) and in the beginning of my code i usually call

```
import gdal
gdal.RegisterAll()
```

However it has been reported by multiple users of my program that with never versions of gdal (1.9.2 for instance) this raises an AttributeError (AttributeError: ‘module’ object has no attribute ‘AllRegister’”) saying that the `RegisterAll()` function is unknown.
This error was reported for both Windows and Linux systems.

Anyone has an Idea about what has changed and if you still need to Register the drivers in newer gdal versions? This is probably a question for the developer-mailing list, but maybe some people are reading this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use it—it's unnecessary. From the [GDAL API Tutorial](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html):

> Python automatically calls GDALAllRegister() when the gdal module is imported.

Comment: thanks!, Nevertheless i am curious why it has been removed. I am currently building some _hasattr_ if-phrases around these parts.

Comment: With OGR, there is `ogr.RegisterAll()`, and with GDAL there is `gdal.AllRegister()` (swapped words). However, *neither*  of these need to be called, so don't bother using them or building `hasattr` logic to support it. I can't pin down any history if the calls were ever required.